# Customize reading pandas data frame of type pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am trying to read the pandas dataframe of kind:
[image]

The second column is a vector. But, I would like to keep only one element of the array like this:

```
     LHELeptE       LHEWeights[1]  LHELeptEta   
0    452.352448     0.058107431    0.262128
1    386.208362     0.061302057    -1.426716
```

Please let me know how I can do this?

Comment: Input is `csv file`? Or another df with `list`s? Then need `df['LHEWeights[1]'] = df['LHEWeights'].str[1]`

Comment: How do you read your CSV currently? You can pass a converter to `read_csv` so you don't even read the data in.

Comment: @jezrael: no input is not csv file. Its root file (https://root.cern.ch). Your suggestation worked.. Thanks

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks again. Earlier I read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str but did not get it. Now I understand its use. :)